# Controlling YouTube swfobject with Flash JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, flash, youtube-api, swfobject

Is it possible to use [Flash JavaScript API](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/publishexport/scriptingwithflash/scriptingwithflash_03.html) with YouTube videos?  The only function that I got to work reasonably is "Zoom".  `TotalFrames()` gives "1" and `TCurrentFrame('/')` is always "0".  Other functions seem to do nothing. For testing this I'm just using the live [Google Playground Demo](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#chromeless_player) with "ytplayer" as the movie object.

Most of what I want to do can be done with the Google API, but I still feel uncomfortably unclear on the three way relationship of YouTube videos, swfobject, and Flash.  Enlightenment appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend building solutions on the JavaScript API described in the page you link to, or spending much time digging in to it, as you can see in the title it's about Flash Player 5, that was released 10 years ago.

I guess it may still be there in the current Flash Player, to some extent, but overall it has a feel of being mostly deprecated, talking about stuff like "execute the action in the frame specified by frameNumber" and such. That is hardly how most Flash apps are built these days, having different "actions" in different frames of the main timeline and such. In other words, it's an API suitable for Flash content produced 10 years ago, hardly for stuff like the current YouTube player.

Comment: So is it accurate to say that is really up to the Flash app developer to decide how they want to expose a JavaScript interface?  In this case that means stick with the YouTube API?

Comment: Yes, in practice, that is pretty much how it is.